# CSS Text styling - fill text using animation with the numbers 1 and 0 - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do the following, however not sure if this possible/ how to go about doing it. Is it possible to do this animation in CSS styling.

The below is the HTML - I am trying to generate some animation to fill the following text with the numbers 1 and 0. I have managed to get some javascript going to create an animation for 1,0 but not sure how to fill 'DEVELOPER' with text to make up each letter.

```js
var outputbinary = document.querySelector(".output");

var optionsarray = [0, 1];
var binaryarray = [];


setInterval(function() {

  if (binaryarray.length <= 2000) {
    var binarynumber = optionsarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionsarray.length)];
    binaryarray.push(binarynumber);
    var str = binaryarray.join(" ");
    outputbinary.innerText = str;
  }

}, 10);
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
<div class="loading">Developer</div>
<div>
```

I want the the text developer to be displayed like

```
 111  0000
 1  1 0
 1  1 000
 1  1 0
 111  0000 //etc
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. You want to turn 'Developer' in to what?

Comment: I want developer to be animated somehow. I would like each letter to fade into the screen and rather than it have a css styling of a colour e.g grey... I want the numbers 1 and 0 to make each letter rather than a solid colour. Does this make sense?

Comment: I made an edit to your question - is that what you mean? If not - roll it back.

Comment: That’s exactly what I mean.. thank you. I am happy for it to alternate 1,0 even on one letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example builds letters from a series of zeros and ones, adds them to the page, and fades them in.

It displays them in a list. Each list item has a container that displays the sub-units using CSS grid.

```js
const mapping = {
  D: '1111010001100011000111110',
  E: '1111110000111101000011111',
  V: '1000110001100010101000100',
  O: '0111010001100011000101110',
  L: '1000010000100001000011111',
  P: '1111010001111101000010000',
  R: '1111010001111101000110001'
};

// Grab the binary mapping of the letter and
// return some HTML
function binaryise(letter) {
  const arr = mapping[letter].split('');
  return arr.map(char => `<div class="${char === '0' ? 'zero' : 'one'}">${char}</div>`).join('');
}
  
// For each letter in the word create a 
// binary version and return it in a list-item container
function processWord(arr) {
  const items = arr.map((letter, i) => {
    const binaryised = binaryise(letter);
    return `
      <li data-id=${i}>
        <div class="container">${binaryised}</div>
      </li>
    `;
  }).join('');
  return `<url>${items}</ul>`;
}

// Get a random number that hasn't previously appeared
function getRandom(arr, memo) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return memo.includes(index) ? getRandom(arr, memo) : index;  
}

// Once the html has been added to the page
// (all set with opacity to 0)
// iterate over the letters turning the
// opacity of each to 1
function showLetters(arr, memo) {
  memo = memo || [];
  if (memo.length !== arr.length) {
    const index = getRandom(arr, memo);
    const letter = arr[index];
    const el = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${index}"]`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      el.classList.add('show');
      memo.push(index);
      showLetters(arr, memo);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

var wordArr = 'Developer'.toUpperCase().split('');

// Process all the letters of the word and add them
// to the page...
const html = processWord(wordArr);
output.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

// ...then fade them in
showLetters(wordArr);
```

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 4s linear;
}

.zero {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```